# Problema ao conectar com MS SQL Server. O mesmo código C# não funciona em Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-forms

Atualizando... 
Já consegui acessar o banco pelo Android o problema era a porta que não estava configurada.
Agora tem outra questão quando eu faço o Debug do codigo para o android funciona mas se eu fazer o debug no computador local da erro no SQL. sera que tenho que dar alguma permissão para o meu app para desktop??

### O problema a baixo com o codigo ja foi resolvido.

Preciso conectar ao SQL por um app fizo teste em C# usando windows forms

```
 try
        {
            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection((string)@"server=SERVIDORHP\PDVNET; database=BDBANCO; uid=sa; pwd=MINHASENHA123;");
             conexao.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Todo ok");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro", ex.Message);
        }
```

Funcionou como o esperado, mas quando se trata do Xamarim forms ultilizo o codigo.

```
try
        {



            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection((string)@"server=SERVIDORHP\PDVNET; database=BDBANCO; uid=sa; pwd=MINHASENHA123;");
                            cmd.Connection = conexao;               
            conexao.Open();


            conexao.Close();
            DisplayAlert("Todo ok.","Conexão bem sucedida!", "OK");                
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Erro", e.Message, "OK");                
        }
```

Dai já retorna a mensagem

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Obs: Baixei o System.Data.SQLclient(4.6.0) do pacote NuGet
é o oficial da Microsoft.

Comment: Experimente colocar o IP ao invés do nome da máquina. Ex.: `server=192.168.1.1\PDVNET`

Comment: tentei dessa forma tambem e da o mesmo problema

Comment: Eu enxergo duas possibilidades. Uma é que o dispositivo que está executando o Xamarin Forms não enxerga a máquina em que está hospedado o SQLServer. Outra possibilidade é que o dispositivo enxerga a máquina mas não consegue abrir a porta de comunicação com o Servidor. 
Ai tem que ver se o dispositivo é real ou emulado, pois cada um tem sua abordagem se for esse o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Bom Dia amigo, tenta dessa maneira.

```
  string connectionString = "server=SERVIDORHP\PDVNET; database=BDBANCO; uid=sa; pwd=MINHASENHA123;"

         using SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        {
          conexao.Open();
          DisplayAlert("Todo ok.","Conexão bem sucedida!", "OK"); 
        }
```